# Cannot create dataproc cluster due to SSD label error

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I've been creating dataproc clusters successfully over the past couple of weeks using the following gcloud command:

> gcloud dataproc --region us-east1 clusters create test1 --subnet
>   default --zone us-east1-c --master-machine-type n1-standard-4
>   --master-boot-disk-size 250 --num-workers 10 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 --worker-boot-disk-size 200 --num-worker-local-ssds 1
>   --image-version 1.2 --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' --project MyProject
>   --initialization-actions gs://MyBucket/MyScript.sh

But today I'm getting the following error when I try to create dataproc cluster from either gcloud cli or the GCP web console:

> ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation
>   [projects/MyProject/regions/us-east1/operations/SOMELONGIDHERE]
>   failed: Invalid value for field
>   'resource.disks[1].initializeParams.labels': ''. Cannot specify
>   initializeParams.labels for local SSD..

I tried changing the cluster name and the zone (not region), without any success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Worked after changing Region to us-central1 !!! (also changed name, but not sure if that factors in)
Not sure If I should add this as answer since this seems to be a bad workaround for a bug on GCP end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue on Google's end that was corrected.
It should be working now.